# How To Add Values Group By Colum In a Data Table?

Tags: c#

i am trying to add `KW` vales group by data in data table but I cant?? I have filterd the values in data table group by date but cant add adding them does any one know how to add them??

```
DataTable _GHdt = _Hdt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "DATE");
```

this line just filtering the date while `_Ghdt` and `_Hdt` are data tables

hopes for your suggestions

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood corectly but do you want to write a GroupBy over a DataTable
[You can do that .](http://weblogs.asp.net/wenching/archive/2008/05/16/linq-datatable-query-group-aggregation.aspx)

If I didnot understand your question properly please try to spend some more time explaining it , what is the data you have and what have you tried etc..

Comment: yup you have got right i wanna do group by on a data table want to add KW values group by Date in a data table

Comment: Look at the link i have in the answer http://weblogs.asp.net/wenching/archive/2008/05/16/linq-datatable-query-group-aggregation.aspx

Comment: Hi all, i do not want to use LINQ i want to do it using data view is there any method in data view to sum "KW" column group by "DATE" column Present in data view??